# How to get the parent control of WindowsFormsHost?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In my application, add my control(WF) in WindowsFormsHost and add this host in Window(WPF).

```
WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost();
host.Child = grid; //this is instance of WF control
testwindow.testSurface.Children.Add(host); // add in Window(WPF)
```

**Query:**
Now i need to get the Handle value of "testWindow" from "grid" (in WF project not WPF) to capture image of testWindow.

I have tried "grid.Parent as WinFormsAdapter", but it is internal class. I found the below articles but it all shows in WPF project.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/469f21db-c9cb-4e9c-a29a-b90722032cd1/how-to-find-the-winform-controls-parent-windowsformshost?forum=wpf

Please anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the `WindowsFormsHost` from the `grid`. Once you have that, you can try working your way up to get the parent of `WindowsFormsHost`.

```
Control parent = grid.Parent;
Reflection.Assembly adapterAssembly = GetType(WindowsFormsHost).Assembly;
Type adapterType = adapterAssembly.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WinFormsAdapter");
object adapterParent = adapterType.InvokeMember("_host", BindingFlags.NonPublic |BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance, null, adapter, new object[] {});
WindowsFormsHost winHost = adapterParent as WindowsFormsHost;
```

Please note the above code is not tested but it is meant to help and hopefully guide you towards the end goal.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Now i can get the parent of WindowsFormsHost. but  
Handle (IntPtr) value is returned as "0", so i can't get the image.

Control adapter = DataGrid.Parent;
Assembly asm = typeof(WindowsFormsHost).Assembly;
Type type = asm.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WinFormsAdapter");
object parent = type.InvokeMember("_host", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance, null, adapter, new Object[] { });
WindowsFormsHost host = parent as WindowsFormsHost;
Window tw = (Window)host.Parent;
IntPtr twHandle = WindowInteropHelper(tw).Handle;

Comment: I have tried this below code, which is working fine
var windows = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows;
IntPtr twHandle = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(windows[2]).Handle;